# I need to calculate slot utilisation for a clinic (re-book rate)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data in a table called activity, which holds information on clinic times, when an appointment starts and when it ends, these slots are identified using as scheduleID which uniquely identifies a slot, I have other columns which hold information on whether a person attended this slot (attend, DNA, cancelled).

My task is to calculate a rebook rate, find out how many slots were cancelled and the date they were cancelled (datediff) and whether it was subsequently re-booked and the date it was re-booked.

I have  written the query which selects for a given period the number of appts that were cancelled, this gives a list of all appt slots that were cancelled, eg. scheduleID, date_apptmentstart, apptend, whether attended or not, (e.g. attend, cancel,) the date when the appointment was cancelled, whether the slot was rebooked and somebody attended.

I then joined the table onto itself to find whether the slot was rebooked, this can return multiple rows (duplicates) since the slot can be booked and cancelled multiple times before somebody attends, i need to find the difference between the time the slot was cancelled and the when it was r-ebooked and somebody attended. I need to calculate the re-book rate using the result set below.   I think i have the right result set, i.e. looking for a datediff between canceldate and slotdate (i.e. the apptstartdate) based on whether it was re-booked, Thanks.

create table appointments 
as

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[appointments](
  [scheduleID] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  [Apptstartdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [Apptenddate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [attend_description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
  [datecancelled] (datetime) NULL
  [clinicsession] nvarchar (30) NOT NULL

  GO

select
     a.scheduleID,
     a.clinicsession
     a.apptstartDate,
     a.apptendDate,
     a.Attend_description,
     a.Datecancelled,

     datediff(day, b.canceldate,a.appt_startdate) as daysTocancel,

     b.scheduleid,
     b.apptstartDate,
     b.apptendDate,
     b.appt_Createdate,
     b.attend_description,
     b.canceldate,

    case
       when a.canceldate is null then 1 else
       0 end as [SlotFilled]

      FROM  Activity as a

      inner join Activity as b
      on a.scheduleid=b.scheduleid and
      b.apptstartdate>=b.apptstartdate

      where left(a.attend_description,4) = 'canc' and
      a.ApptSTARTdate between '03-apr-2018' and '04-apr-2018'
```

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Please provide more details:Tables' structure, some sample data for each table, the query you've got so far and what does work with it and what doesn't...

Comment: Here are some tools and guidelines you can use to help us help you: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/